# How to make GroovyBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions from input stream

Tags: spring, groovy, javabeans

as GroovyBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions from Resource only today, but we're trying to load from input stream rather than file.
so is there any way out?

meanwhile, i'm implementing a new subclass GroovyStreamBeanDefinitionReader extends GroovyBeanDefinitionReader to add one more loadBeanDefinitions from input stream, but still i'd like to ask the community is there something similar existing or better solutions

thanks